# Stop css transition to move other elements on hover

Tags: css

How can i get the second image not to move when hovering first image and vice versa? Right now the non-hovering image is changing its position.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lswbf7ou/

```
<img class="first-hover" src="http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121125171115/bradlykart/images/0/09/100px-ToadtheShroom.png"/>
<img class="second-hover" src="http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121125171115/bradlykart/images/0/09/100px-ToadtheShroom.png"/> 

img.first-hover {
height:80px;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; ;
 -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
 -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

img.second-hover {
height:80px;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; ;
 -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
 -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

img.first-hover:hover {
height:100px;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; ;
 -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
 -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

img.second-hover:hover {
height:100px;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; ;
 -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
 -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: You'll have to give it an absolute position, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lswbf7ou/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `position: absolute`, check that jsfiidle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jcskc4hk/

Answer (score 0):

You should us `position` in `img.first-hover`,`img.second-hover` classes.

```
img.first-hover {
    height:80px;
     -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; ;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
     -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     position: absolute;
}

img.second-hover {
    left:70px;
    height:80px;
     -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; ;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
     -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     position: absolute;
}
```