# stop movement of elements when hovering on other element

Tags: html, css, hover, move

HI i am building a [site](http://new.bluprintwebsolutions.co.za/) with genesis and dynamik.  On the Home page with dynamik at the top there are 3 widgets. I created 3 more underneath the top three.

My problem is when I hover on any one of the elements the rest "jumps" around. All that the hover does is to adjust the element size from 300px to 350px.

How do I manage it that only the "active" element being hover on reacts and the other 5 stays static?

I might have found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26504103/stop-css-transition-to-move-other-elements-on-hover) BUT i am still lost. Bit too new at this I believe.
The two lines of code

Does this go into a html file? I am using Wordpress and these 6 fields are populated using widgets.

From the solution I understand that I have to create first-hover to six-hover with six of the lines of code linking the images to the class.

And the using the position:absolute;

If my take on this is correct please let me know and just advice me how do I do the

code and where.

Thx

Comment: Which part of your code has `<div id="ez-feature-top-2" class="widget-area ez-widget-area one-third">` ? could you copy this area to the question please

Answer (score 0):

You should set the css in `\wp-content\themes\the-theme-you-use\style.css`, for example it could be like this:

```
.dynamik-widget-area.feature {
  position: absolute; 
}
```

Just place this anywhere at the end of the file.

Another solution is to add `style="position: absolute"` to the first `<div>` element in the following part:

```
<div   style="position: absolute"  id="ez_feature_6" class="widget-area dynamik-widget-area ez feature 6">
  <section id="black-studio-tinymce-39" class="widget widget_black_studio_tinymce">
    <div class="widget-wrap">
      <div class="textwidget"><p style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://new.bluprintwebsolutions.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/diy1billboard.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-64" src="http://new.bluprintwebsolutions.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/diy1billboard-300x300.jpg" alt="diy1billboard" width="300" height="300"></a></p>
</div></div></section>
</div>
```

However note that this will solve the overlapping problem, but in return you'll have to reposition the elements.

Repositioning can be done using css too, using for example `left` attribute. Something like:

```
.second{
  left: 100px;
}
```

then add second to the classes of that

```
<div   style="position: absolute"  id="ez_feature_2" class="widget-area dynamik-widget-area ez feature 6 second">
```